# List of <li> hidding beyond a certain point

Tags: css, html

I have a `<header>` with 20

```
<li></li>'s
```

in it with years going back 20 years. Within the header I want to show 100% screen width worth of years with the 2012 `<li>` being at the far right. Any easy way to do this? I really need it in a long horizontal line because I am going to be creating a parallex effect on hover to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5%;
    text-align: center;
}
```